# how to i get my function to recognise a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my function

```
def PredictCorner(Home_Team, Away_Team):
    Home_Average = Table_Current_Normalised.loc["Average", "Att_Home"]
    Away_Average = Table_Current_Normalised.loc["Average", "Att_Away"]
    AH = Table_Current_Normalised.loc[Home_Team, "Att_Home"] / Home_Average
    DH = Table_Current_Normalised.loc[Home_Team, "Def_Home"] / Away_Average
    AA = Table_Current_Normalised.loc[Away_Team, "Att_Away"] / Away_Average
    DA = Table_Current_Normalised.loc[Away_Team, "Def_Away"] / Home_Average
    Rate_Home = AH * DA * Home_Average
    Rate_Away = AA * DH * Away_Average
    return [Rate_Home,Rate_Away]
```

and the df in question is Table_Current_Normalised.

This is the error I get
`NameError: name 'Table_Current_Normalised' is not defined`

Thanks in advance, am new to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, the function can't find any object with the name `Table_Current_Normalised`. Because this name isn't a parameter or assigned within your function, it's assumed to be a *globally defined variable*. IE it is defined or imported somewhere in the body of the module, not inside a function.

More than likely, the problem you have is either:

(1) you have called this function before the global df exists
(2) You have defined the df in a local scope (within another function)
(3) there is a typo in the name.

For instance, here, the function `do_something` is called before the name `d` is defined:

```
def do_something():
    d['foo'] = 'bar'
do_something()  # NameError
d = {}
```

Or if you define `d` in the *local* scope of another function, you'll have a similar problem.

```
def do_something():
    d['foo'] = 'bar'
def main():    
    d = {} # d is _local_ to the function ``main``
    do_something()  # NameError
```

This results in both cases is the error `NameError: name 'd' is not defined`

To address, we make sure that `d` is defined globally before calling the function:

```
def do_something():
    d['foo'] = 'bar'
d = {}
def main():
    do_something()
    print(d)
main()
```

This works as expected.

Further, you should consider rewriting this function to accept the dataframe as an argument. That way, it won't rely on some globally-defined variable.

```
def PredictCorner(Home_Team, Away_Team, table_current):
    Home_Average = table_current.loc["Average", "Att_Home"]
    Away_Average = table_current.loc["Average", "Att_Away"]
    AH = table_current.loc[Home_Team, "Att_Home"] / Home_Average
    DH = table_current.loc[Home_Team, "Def_Home"] / Away_Average
    AA = table_current.loc[Away_Team, "Att_Away"] / Away_Average
    DA = table_current.loc[Away_Team, "Def_Away"] / Home_Average
    Rate_Home = AH * DA * Home_Average
    Rate_Away = AA * DH * Away_Average
    return [Rate_Home,Rate_Away]
```

Then call it like so:

```
PredictCorner(home_team, away_team, Table_Current_Normalised)
```